# Teradata SQL Tuning. Aliasing a union all column in a dervied table

Tags: sql, teradata, data-warehouse, union-all, sqlperformance

I am sure I might be missing something  but is there a way I can alias the resultant data-set column that comes of a derived table

```
    sel tb1.C1
      , Tb2.C2
      , ( sel DC1.Col1  
          from ( DC1 logic here) DC1  
          UNION ALL 
          DC2.col2 
          from ( DC2 Logic here ) DC2 
        ) D_outer 
    where conditions
```

I want to alias the Column in D_outer that comes off DC1.col1 UNION ALL DC2.col2
so I can call it for other stuff , I am trying to do

Comment: I reformatted your SQL but it appears to be incomplete. Typically, the column aliases and data types are driven by the first `SELECT` statement in the `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks Rob PL post as answer so I can vote up and tick off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your SQL but it appears to be incomplete. Typically, the column aliases and data types are driven by the first SELECT statement in the UNION